# Combining Error between equal size data sets

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am trying to know if there is another way of adding two data sets together and then obtaining the standard deviation of the combined set. Currently, these data sets have equal numbers of subjects. What I am doing is putting all the results together and then simply getting the standard deviation from the combined set. There is no difference between the two sets, just that one experiment was performed at a later time but with the same conditions (i.e. I just wanted to increase the total population count for better statistics).

My questions is: is there a more correct way of doing this than adding the sets together? or should I analyze each data set individually? if so then how could I get a single standard deviation value for the entire population?

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,
JohnWick

Comment: If one experiment was done first and the others later, then the question arises whether the early and late ones are really equivalent. Maybe start by getting separate confidence intervals for each expt separately, see if the CIs overlap convincingly. Then maybe you have some justification for combining them. // In a paper or report you'd need to disclose that there were two separate experiments and that they were combined for reasons you can defend.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response I will check the CI of each set and compare! These samples are actually just films that I have prepared in the lab and tested them mechanically in tension. So in theory the early and later samples are equivalent as the same material batch was used.